# Drafting SQL search entry to check if variable is is within range of values on table

Tags: mysql

I'm currently using the following SQL query for a room booking service online:

```
$myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE Capacity >= "'.$Capacity.'" AND Location LIKE "'.$Location.'%" AND RoomType LIKE "'.$RoomType.'%"';
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to search for given Capacity. For example if the user inputs 20 Capacity then it should search for all the rooms with 20 capacity and over. How can I achieve this?

Comment: looks like you did it already...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - when I search for rooms with 500 capacity it still returns me results when there are no rooms with 500 capacity

Comment: Is `Capacity` a `VARCHAR` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the `VARCHAR` field before performing a numeric comparison:

```
WHERE CONVERT(Capacity, SIGNED) >= $Capacity
```

Make sure not to put any quotes around `$Capacity`.

Comment: Alternatively shoot whoever specified a field that is blatently numeric, Capacity, as being VARCHAR and get them to change it to a more sensible type such as SMALLINT (as I've yet to see a hotel with more than 65k rooms)